# PHP - get value from JSON

Tags: php, json

Before i decode my JSON i get this result:

```
{
"1":[{"membership_id":1,"group_id":1,"user_id":1},
"2":[{"membership_id":3,"group_id":1,"user_id":2}
}
```

How would i specify that i want to select the one who has 'user_id' == 2 and return membership_id value?

My attempt, but i get undefined value 'user_id':

```
$myjson = json_decode($s_o, true);
    foreach ($myjson as $key => $value){
        if($value['user_id'] == $cid){
            $mid = $value['membership_id'];
        }
    }
    echo $mid;
```

Basically i guess i would first have to select the right object and go through it with the foreach, but here i got a bit lost in the situation.

Comment: `var_dump($value)`

Comment: When you decode your JSON you get more JSON? (Well, sort of JSON, at least)

Comment: Please show your original, un-decoded json string.

Comment: My bad, before i decode, i miswrote that

Comment: [`array_values`](http://php.net/array_values) and [`array_column`](http://php.net/array_column) should suffice to get a map for user_id→membership_id.

Comment: That isn't valid JSON. You're missing several closing `]` brackets.

Comment: How did you create that JSONString. It is not valid. If it was created in your code you had better show us that code as well

Comment: What does `var_dump($s_o)` look like?

Comment: If the subarrays may contain multiple sets of member data, you should represent that in your sample data so that solutions don't naively leverage `[0]` to access the deepest values.  If there is ALWAYS only one set of member values in each subarray, then I would argue that you are handling a suboptimal data structure and one "level" can be removed for better processing.

Answer (score 1):

Use Array-Functions:

```
$json = '{
"1":[{"membership_id":1,"group_id":1,"user_id":1}],
"2":[{"membership_id":3,"group_id":1,"user_id":2}]
}';

$array = json_decode($json, true);
$searchUserID = 2;

$filteredArray = array_filter($array, function($elem) use ($searchUserID){
    return $searchUserID == $elem[0]['user_id'];
});

$mid = array_column(array_shift($filteredArray), 'membership_id')[0];

echo "Membership-ID: ".$mid;
```

`array_filter` uses a callback function that iterates over every element of the array. If the callback function returns true, that element is assigned to `$filteredArray`. No need for a foreach loop that way.
But the return value is the whole array element:

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [membership_id] => 3
                    [group_id] => 1
                    [user_id] => 2
                )

        )

)
```

So you have to extract your membership_id.

Read the following line from inside out.
First, we fetch the first entry of the array with `array_shift` (since we have only one entry, this will be our desired entry).

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [membership_id] => 3
            [group_id] => 1
            [user_id] => 2
        )

)
```

We pass this array on to `array_column` to find the entry in the encapsulated array with the column name `membership_id`. Since array_column again returns an array,

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
)
```

we get the (one and only) entry by adding [0] to the end of this command.

Since the last part is a little complicated, here's a torn apart version of it:

```
$firstEntryOfFilteredArray = array_shift($filteredArray);

$arrayWithValueOfColumnMembershipID = array_column($firstEntryOfFilteredArray, 'membership_id');

$membership_id = $arryWithValueOfColumnMembershipID[0];
```

These three lines are concatenated into this:

```
$mid = array_column(array_shift($filteredArray), 'membership_id')[0];
```

here's a working example: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8fe6ede71ca1e09dc68b2f3bec51743b27bf5303

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the JSON actually looks like:

```
{
"1":[{"membership_id":1,"group_id":1,"user_id":1}],
"2":[{"membership_id":3,"group_id":1,"user_id":2}]
}
```

Each element of the object is an array for some reason. So you need to index it with `$value[0]` to access the object contained inside it.

```
$myjson = json_decode($s_o, true);
foreach ($myjson as $key => $value){
    if($value[0]['user_id'] == $cid){
        $mid = $value[0]['membership_id'];
        break;
    }
}
echo $mid;
```

If the arrays can contain multiple elements, you'll need nested loops.

```
$myjson = json_decode($s_o, true);
foreach ($myjson as $key => $value){
    foreach ($value as $object) {
        if($object['user_id'] == $cid){
            $mid = $object['membership_id'];
            break 2;
        }
    }
}
echo $mid;
```

Comment: Unless you know better, I dont think the Json String is valid :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly See the first line of my answer.

Comment: Otherwise the decode would be failing and he would get an error about trying to use `foreach` with an invalid value.

Comment: Ahhh subtile :) :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit speculative, but I think the data is indexed by user ID. If that's the case, it makes the lookup much simpler.

After decoding with `$myjson = json_decode($s_o, true);`

Just find the record by ID and get the membership_id from the matching row.

```
$membership_id = reset($myjson['2'])['membership_id'];`
```

You should probably verify that that ID exists, so maybe something like:

```
$membership_id = isset($myjson['2']) ? reset($myjson['2'])['membership_id'] : null;
```

If I'm wrong and the fact that the row numbers match the user_id is just a coincidence, then never mind :)

Comment: If the array comes from a DB-Query, you'll get the results just in the order they were entered into the DB which doesn't necessarily correlate with the user_id

Comment: If your speculation is incorrect, perhaps hedge your answer by offering a solution that specifically checks the `user_id` value.

Comment: @Swissdude That is certainly true, and I think that data probably did come from a database at some point. But if it was just a JSON-encoded array of query results, you'd have sequential indexes starting with zero, which would end up creating a JSON array, not an object with numeric keys. Some ORMs produce results with the rows indexed by the entity ID that look kind of like this. I was thinking it might be something like that.

Comment: @mickmackusa I thought Barmar's answer had already covered that well enough. I was just offering a different approach based on a possibility I noticed. I figured even if it turns out not to be applicable to this OP, it could still be applicable to someone else with a similar set of data.